# Is it legal to use the address of a member to initialize a base-class?

Tags: c++, initialization, undefined-behavior

Is this code legal?:

```
class BaseClass
{
  public:
    BaseClass (int *p) : p_ (p) { }

  private:
    int *p_;
};

class SubClass : public BaseClass
{
  public:
    SubClass () : BaseClass (&i_), i_ (123) {}

  private:
    int i_;
};
```

It is well-known that the base-class gets constructed before the members of the sub-class, which is why I'm wondering.

Comment: As long as the base class does not dereference the pointer before the derived class is initialized I believe it is valid.

Comment: Almost a variant of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020255/in-the-member-initializer-list-can-i-create-a-reference-to-a-member-variable-no

Comment: Just wondering who are downvoting this!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine: while the *lifetime* of (the relevant instance of) `SubClass::i` has yet to begin, its storage exists, and a pointer to it may be formed (though not [used for much](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) yet).