# Is this C++ member initialization behavior well defined?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, undefined-behavior, default-constructor

Let's assume we have a class `B` that has a `member` which is default initialized to `42`. This class knows how to print the value of its `member` (it does so in the constructor):

```
struct B
{
  B() : member(42) { printMember(); }

  void printMember() const { std::cout << "value: " << member << std::endl; }

  int member;
};
```

Then we add a class `A` which receives a const reference to a `B` and asks `B` to print its value:

```
struct A
{
  A(const B& b) { b.printMember(); }
};
```

Finally we add another class `Aggregate` that aggregates an `A` and a `B`. The tricky part is that object `a` of type `A` is declared before object `b` type `B`, but then `a` is initialized using a (not yet valid?) reference to `b`:

```
struct Aggregate
{
  A a;
  B b;

  Aggregate() : a(b) { }
};
```

Consider the output of creating an `Aggregate` (I have added some logging to both the constructor and destructor of `A` and `B`) ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFNboMwEIX3nGKUSq2J0qqqujIoEux7CP@MKBLYyNjZROnViSGY1FUDXlgznvH3PM@i614rIYYB/HqqlWicRMhr3VuDrD0myVjwiRMWyik5TztASdI5otDrFr@w5WjI50c4Do3jfUmp0M5CnsOOg3ix2uzGZKqgkk22NHemVnaGpeH4kszBz132MV8@5i@gk65lrAVCq95uwE@scUjhBl@mXpfyGr96b@VLFllbRNYWZHoKlM/At6Zl627ytw0/C7KtsOrnf9NUlcGKWYynAhZulcCz8IKl2f8ABUZ4Cuc/2NHAltUKiI8OIL6Z2e/TGB4odxGD1hkF77PhyTBcAQ)):

```
a c'tor
value: 0
b c'tor
value: 42
b d'tor
a d'tor
```

Am I right to assume that it is invalid to initialize `a` with a reference to a (not yet valid) instance of `b` and that this is therefore undefined behavior?

---

I am aware of the initialization order. This is what makes me struggle. I *know* that `b` is not yet constructed, but I also *think* to know that `b`'s future address can be determined even before `b` is constructed. Therefore I assumed there *could be some rule that I am not aware of* that allows the compiler to default initialize `b`s members prior to `b`'s construction or something like that. (It would have been more obvious if the first printed out value would have been something that looks random rather than `0` (the default value of `int`)).

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50020703/10065681) helped me understand that I need to distinguish between

- *binding a reference* to an uninitialized object (which is valid) and
- *accessing by reference* an uninitialized object (which is undefined)

Comment: If you switch their order in the class definition, it will have better defined behavior. Alternatively, don't use the reference to access the object (see here for a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020255/in-the-member-initializer-list-can-i-create-a-reference-to-a-member-variable-no).

Comment: I know how to "fix" it. What I am not sure about is, whether it *should* be fixed (as it's ugly) or *must* be fixed (because it's undefined behavior and therefore simply broken) ;)

Comment: What you display *is broken*. The example in the other question is not. It's a mine-field of standardese

Comment: You are using object before it has been initialized. Why do you think you shouldn't fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Initialization Order of Class Data Members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669888/c-initialization-order-of-class-data-members)

Comment: `b` is not valid. The *reference to `b`* is valid, but it is a reference to an object that was not constructed yet; it can be used in certain limited ways, but not in the way you have used it.

Comment: @n.m. I very much like this comment. It certainly helps me understand my actual problem.

Comment: The relevant section of the draft standard is \[basic.life], paragraph 7 ("Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started...")

Comment: Related to [Is passing a C++ object into its own constructor legal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32608458/1708801) ... the answer is here but the question is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you are right that it is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but for different reasons than just storing a reference to an object that hasn't been constructed.

Construction of class members happens in order of their appearance in the class. Although the address of `B` is not going to change and technically you [can store a reference to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50020703/8414561), as @StoryTeller pointed out, calling `b.printMember()` in the constructor with `b` that hasn't been constructed yet is definitely UB.

Answer (score 1):

The order of initialization of class members is as below.

**From CPP standard (N4713), the relevant portion is highlighted:**

> 15.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]
>   ...
>   13 In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>   (13.1) — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (6.6.2), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>   (13.2) — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
>   (13.3) — **Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).**
>   (13.4) — Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.
>   [ Note: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of initialization. —end note ]

Comment: `By the time, the constructor of Aggregate is called, the constructors of a (first) and b (next) are already called` — you seem to be confusing `Aggregate` and `A`, or something else. The statement doesn't appear to make sense.

Comment: @Ruslan: Edited, see if it appears proper now.

Comment: No, I still don't get what you mean by that sentence. What exactly is not undefined behavior? The UB has already happened by the time that initialization is done — at the stage of calling the constructor of `a`.

Comment: Yes, UB has happened at the construction of a. But after its construction, `member` has a certain value, whatever that value is. So using that value in construction of Aggregate is not UB. But the overall behaviour is UB.

Comment: No it hasn't. After UB you can't tell the state of the program — the program may no longer exist, or appear to be in multiple states at the same time or whatever...

Comment: And since UB allows time travel (or at least overwriting past results wherever they might be stored), you can't even reason backwards _before_ UB.